# getpathtranslated returns null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

The thing I try to implement the method getPathTranslated () but always returns null, this is the method I use:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class FileLocation extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        //response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        if (request.getPathInfo() != null) {
            out.println("The file \"" + request.getPathInfo() + "\"");
            out.println("Is stored at \"" + request.getPathTranslated() + "\"");
        } else {
            out.println("Path info is null, no file to lookup");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to retrieve the filesystem path corresponding to a URL path, try `getServletContext().getRealPath("your_path")`.

Comment: Then getPathtranslated that it serves, or useful?

Answer (score 0):

Try this line:

`request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length())`

Comment: Then getPathtranslated that it serves, or useful?

Answer (score 0):

> In situations where the servlet container cannot determine a valid file path for getRealPath or getPathTranslated methods, such as when the Web application is executed from an archive, on a remote file system not accessible locally, or in a database, these methods must return null.

The getPathTranslated method computes the real path of the pathInfo of the request.

If there is not a situation check your Servlet Mapping in deployment descriptor.

If you have a situation like:

```
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
```

then you must know that observed path element behavior is like following (assume your request path is /myapp/admin/mypage.xhtml)

```
ContextPath: /myapp
ServletPath: /admin/mypage.xhtml
PathInfo: null
```

Hope it will help you to analyze a problem from a different point of view.